# When I import and edit a .fbx file and export with Blender, the file size gets bigger than it was

Tags: export, .fbx

I have some files from Unity, they are **3.6 MB** and always keep **2 MB more** when exporting, I don't include anything extra. Can I save with the same file size? Or can the Unity exporter do this but Blender cannot?

Utilizo **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**

Answer (score 0):

different softwares export things slightly differently. You can't expect the same exact file sizes from both Unity and Blender. File sizes will always be slightly different. :)